# Generated files by caliburn.micro in Release directory

Tags: c#, wpf, file, release, caliburn.micro

Caliburn.Micro generates a lot of files in my Release directory. Do I need to include them all while distributing package with my application? Is it possible to disable copying those files?

- Caliburn.Micro.Platform.xml
- Caliburn.Micro.xml
- directories like *de, en, es* etc. with a single file: *System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll*

These *.xml files look like meta-data for Caliburn.

My application will only support English, so maybe I could remove other directories, but I'm not sure if Caliburn will use it according to system settings or application settings.

I checked the documentation, but I wasn't able to find any description about those files.

Comment: The xml files are documentation/metadata, which intellisense uses to display useful tooltips, so won't need to be deployed. The language specific resource files depend on whether you're supporting those languages, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment.

The xml files are generated documentation used by (among other things) intellisense, so won't need deploying.
The language resources shouldn't need deploying if you don't intend to support those languages.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to disable copying these files every time?

Comment: You could try removing the reference to System.Windows.Interactivity. It's one of the default references, but you may not actually be using it. Other than that, I'll see what my google-fu can dig up.

Comment: I thought those directories are generated by Caliburn, but they are generated by referencing System.Windows.Interactivity. I found the solution to avoid creating those folders every time - just copy dll and add a reference directly to the file. [Link to the original solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/feb23879-660d-43d1-93ef-90a63eef70c6/how-can-i-remove-localization-information-from-my-wpf-project?forum=wpf)

Comment: Yeah, or you could remove the folders from the Blend SDK. Both workarounds seem a bit hacky to me (what if you want localisation in future?), but if it works for you, then that's the main thing.