# Visual Studio Build Solution - How to disable create assembly XML files on Compile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When i build the solution , it was always create some assembly XML files,How should i disable auto create them?Thanks.

Also , i was set the privatePath, but the NuGet item (dll) cannot build in the privatePath. How should i setting?

App.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <probing privatePath="Bin" />
```

assembly XML files:

```
Dapper.xml
Dapper.SimpleCRUD.xml
...
```

Comment: I can't mark this as a duplicate, but check out the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/37925000/7663817

Comment: @AdamDove Thanks,but the XML files and privatePath cannot be solved