# .net core build produces localization folders

Tags: .net-core, publishing

I have a web asp.net solution that is using .net core 2.0. I am building it using the command:

```
dotnet publish MySolution.sln --configuration release --output d:\test_output
```

But when I check the output folder, I'm seeing a lot of localization folders, as you can see in the image bellow:

[image: output content]

Is there a way to publish the code without generating these folders?

Comment: Your question predates it, but the same question, with an answer, is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893450/visual-studio-2017-localization-publish-settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the **.csproj** file, you look for **"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design"** Package reference and add the property **ExcludeAssets="All"**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" ExcludeAssets="All" />
```

Here is the reference: [Disable Dll Culture Folders on Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342061/disable-dll-culture-folders-on-compile)

Answer (score 73):

For the projects using ASP.NET Core 3.1, add this line to your `*.csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>   
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The source of the answer in this post: [Disable Dll Culture Folders on Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655083/5923949).

Comment: Remark: the property should be added inside the existing `<PropertyGroup>` node that contains `<TargetFramework>`, instead of adding a new `<PropertyGroup>`, which I tried first and noticed does not work.

Answer (score 11):

[in net 5.0] All above solutions didn't work for me.
Out of despair I added:

```
<PropertyGroup>   
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en-US;en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and it **worked**, absolutely no idea why

Answer (score 9):

The solution provided by @Igor.K worked for my API project, but for the ASP.NET Core MVC website in my solution, I had to make a minor change.

Try adding the line below to your **.csproj** file.

```
<PropertyGroup>   
    <ResourceLanguages>en</ResourceLanguages>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can edit this file by right-clicking your project and selecting "Unload Project". Then, when you right-click again you will be able to edit the .csproj file. Make sure you reload the project when you're finished though.

So, if **SatelliteResourceLanguages** doesn't solve your problem, **ResourceLanguages** might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the `SateliteResourceLangauges` nor the `ResourceLangauges` solutions worked for me.  In my case the files were being generated by the following nuget:

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" ExcludeAssets="All" />`

Affixing `ExcludeAssets="All"` to it as shown above resolved the issue.

Comment: Your tests should be in a separate project.