# Visual Studio 2017 Localization Publish Settings

Tags: c#, localization, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2, odata

This should be simple, but I haven't found a way to make this stop happening. Visual Studio publishes a lot of localized DLLs - It appears there is German localization, Spanish localization, Italian localization, french localization, Japanese localization, Russian localization and Korean localization. I have an ASP.NET Web API ODATA application, and when I publish the project using Visual Studio 2017, I have these localized dll's taking up unnecessary space in the bin folder. My application only needs to support En-US. How can I make this change? Screenshot of published bin folder:

[image]

Comment: Do you use any external dlls that are localized to these languages?

Comment: No dll's that are localized to my knowledge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Microsoft.CodeAnalysis published with ASP.NET Core website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291135/why-is-microsoft-codeanalysis-published-with-asp-net-core-website)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Open your csproj file with your favorite editor
2. Under the heading `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">` add the line:

`<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin\ar;bin\cs;bin\de;bin\es;bin\fr;bin\he;bin\hi;bin\it;bin\ja;bin\ko;bin\nl;bin\pl;bin\pt;bin\ru;bin\tr-TR;bin\zh-Hans;bin\zh-Hant</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>`

3. Republish your solution

Comment: I do not think this is for .net core

Comment: @DanielWilliams did you find any solution for .Net Core ?

Comment: Yes though I don’t like it. In the post build just have it delete each of those folders.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem for my .NET core 2.0 web API.
It appeared when I moved the solution from a machine to another where a new version of .NET Core was installed: .NET Core 2.1 ; That's why, on publishing all files of .NET core 2.0 where generated. To resolve this issue, I decided to migrate to version 2.1 which solved the issue and the published files were generated smoothly :)

Answer (score -4):

In my case i just remove below item from **csproj file**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.1.0" />
```

Best Regurds

Comment: I don't see this line in the csproj file in the my .NET Core 3.1 project.