# C# WPF creating too many culture folders while building

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, dll, msbuild

Some of my NuGet packages required `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.resources.dll` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.resources.dll` so I installed them.

However, when I build the project, in the Debug folder comes many folders.

[image]

And in each of the folders, there was

[image]

I don't need them, because I only want to display the English language, **I want all other folders to be cleared.**

I manually deleted them and ran the application, it worked fine but I'm afraid if I am running it on a France language Win system, it will pop up an error because the "fr" folder is missing.

---

Also tried adding `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]` in AssemblyInfo.cs, adding `<SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>` under `<PropertyGroup>`. But those folders were still created at the build time.

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Is yours a _ClickOnce_ app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Dll Culture Folders on Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342061/disable-dll-culture-folders-on-compile)

Comment: @MindSwipe the `NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute` doesn't help, as it mentioned in question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add the following target to `csproj` file, where the Nuget package is used

```cs
<Target Name="RemoveSatelliteAssemblies" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceSatellitePaths)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

It'll remove all unnecessary satellite assemblies. If there is a problem with French language, you should leave the target language assemblies

Comment: Nice. The folders r empty now.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me using .Net FrameWork